# fibonacci recursivo mas rapido JAVA

Tags: java

necesito una ayuda enorme con algo. necesito hacer un fibonacci recursivo pero que no tarde tanto como el normal

Modificar el algoritmo para mejorar la velocidad, sin dejar de ser recursivo: Crear un array global para guardar los elementos ya calculados y retornar ese elemento si es que ya fue calculado.

como llamo a al array? en que momento lo llamo? como le digo al array que objeto del fibo recursivo se tiene que guardar?

```
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        int n = 43;

        fibo(n);
        System.out.println(fibo(n));
    }
    public static int fibo(int n){

        if (n == 1 || n == 2)
            return 1;
        else
            return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2);
    }
}
```

gracias

Comment: Si realmente quieres una función rápida, no hace falta que sea recursiva.
Si DEBE ser recursiva, crea una matriz para almacenar los números de fibonacci que vaya encontrando.
La función recursiva, cada vez que quiera un numero de fibonacci, consulta si ya está en la matriz, si ya esta usa el valor almacenado, y si no, la calcula y luego la incluye en la matriz para no tener que volver a calcularla.
No voy a responder con código porque no uso JAVA.

Comment: claro! gracias por la respuesta. lo que ahora no se como aplicar es como llamarla

Comment: Lo que buscas hacer se llama [memoización](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoizaci%C3%B3n). Es una técnica de optimización de procesos recursivos.

Comment: El array no tiene porqué ser global, con que sea estático seria suficiente.

Answer (score 3):

Independientemente de que quieres resolver tu ejercicio usando **recursividad**, puedes usar una técnica conocida como **programación dinámica** para resolver tu problema. Esta técnica reduce considerablemente el tiempo de ejecución de un algoritmo:

```
public static int[] Fibbonacci(int n)
{
   int[] numeros = new int[n];
   
   numeros[0] = 0;
   numeros[1] = 1;

   for(int i = 2; i < n; i++)
   {
      numeros[i] = numeros[i - 1] + numeros[i - 2];
   }

   return numeros;
}
```

En esta función usamos un arreglo para ir generando los **números de fibbonacci**. Las primeras posiciones del arreglo las inicializamos con los valores de **0** y **1** respectivamente. Posteriormente ejecutamos un **ciclo for** el cual irá aplicando la **fórmula de fibbonacci** y se irá guardando en él cada número encontrado. Por último la función retornará el arreglo de **números fibbonacci** calculados.

Para usar esta función podemos hacer:

```
int[] fibs = new int[100];

fibs = Fibbonacci(100);

for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
   //Imprimir fibs[i]
}
```

De esta forma creamos un arreglo de **100** elementos y guardamos en el los **100** primeros **números fibbonacci**, posteriormente imprimimos los elementos del arreglo.

**Nota**: Está técnica de **programación dinámica** es una alternativa que te propongo para que veas que hay otras vías de resolución de algoritmos.

Comment: Esta respuesta no responde a la pregunta, puesto que no usa recursividad -> *Modificar el algoritmo para mejorar la velocidad, **sin dejar de ser recursivo***

Comment: @Benito-B, pero además hacer lo que pide el usuario lleva una respuesta no recursiva, te invito a que le respondas tu al usuario para enseñar tu idea de cómo resolver esta pregunta

Comment: En mi opinión, ni la pregunta deja claro que DEBA usar recursividad, solo que el código actual lo usa, ni lo que pide el usuario lleva necesariamente a una respuesta no recursiva, como he comentado anteriormente. Os invito a tomaros una tila.

Comment: @ArnauCastellví Tienes la palabra "recursivo" en el título, tienes la palabra "recursivo" en el texto, la propia pregunta pone un ejemplo de una función con llamadas a si misma ("recursividad"). Lo de la tila, lo veo un poco sobrante dado que en ningún momento he faltado al respeto ni hablado de malas maneras a nadie (pese a que Japv piense que tengo algo en contra de él o algo, y me responda constante de malas maneras). He puesto un sencillo comentario indicando que esta respuesta no cumple con lo preguntado, dado que no emplea la recursividad. Si hay algún problema con eso, es cosa vuestra.

Comment: @Benito-B Tienes razón, aun así creo que Arkail20 ha expresado la necesidad de mantener la recursividad en una edición de la pregunta.

Comment: @Benito-B, solo quiero terminar diciendo que hay que ser más flexible, no es dar votos negativos porque si. Si la respuesta resuelve el problema y tiene calidad no hagas nada contra ella, déjala, si la respuesta fuera errónea sería otra cosa. Con esta respuesta que di ahora el usuario sabe que hay una nueva técnica de resolución de algoritmos y aporta a la comunidad

Answer (score 0):

Ahora que he tenido un poco más de tiempo, aquí tienes mi propuesta usando recursividad y memoización.
Como siempre, en los comentarios tienes explicaciones de todo y para cualquier duda, no dudes en preguntar

```java
// Primero que nada, declaramos un array donde almacenaremos los números
    public static int[] calculatedNumbers;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 43;
        /* A continuación, instanciamos el array con la longitud máxima igual al número que vamos a calcular
         * +1, así evitamos salirnos de índice al acceder a calculatedNumbers[n] y además no tenemos que
         * poner -1 cada vez que queramos usar el índice.
         */
        calculatedNumbers = new int[n + 1];

        // Ahora hacemos una pequeña prueba para ver si de verdad funciona...
        long startPoint = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(fiboMemoized(n));
        long finishPoint = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("FiboMemoized tardó: " + (finishPoint - startPoint) + " en ejecutarse!");

        startPoint = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(fibo(n));
        finishPoint = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println("Fibo normal tardó: " + (finishPoint - startPoint) + " en ejecutarse!");
    }

    public static int fiboMemoized(int n) {
        /* Ahora se trata de mantener SIEMPRE el array actualizado, así que empezaremos comprobando si
         * ya hemos calculado n o no. Recuerda que un array de int se inicializa a 0! Con lo cual, si ya
         * hemos calculado el número, no entraremos al primer if y directamente lo devolveremos
         */
        if (calculatedNumbers[n] == 0) {
            if (n <= 2) {
                /* Si n es menor a 2, estamos con los primeros números de fibonaci, que son 0 y 1, así que
                 * simplemente guardamos el valor de n-1 en nuestros números calculados!
                 */
                calculatedNumbers[n] = n - 1;
            } else {
                // Si n es mayor, vamos a calcularlo como siempre, nada raro por aquí
                calculatedNumbers[n] = fiboMemoized(n - 1) + fiboMemoized(n - 2);
            }
        }
        // Llegados a este punto, simplemente devolvemos el valor que hayamos guardado al principio!
        return calculatedNumbers[n];
    }

    public static int fibo(int n){

        if (n == 1 || n == 2)
            return 1;
        else
            return fibo(n-1) + fibo(n-2);
    }
```

Para que veas el resultado:
[image: Resultados]

Por cierto, tu método para calcular números de fibonacci parece estar incorrecto, ya que el número 43 en la serie de fibonacci es el 267914296! :)